# The space [0,1] with finite/countable points removed is a T1 space

Tags: general-topology

Exercise from Kolmogorov's Introductory Real Analysis. A closely related question is asked here (but it only addresses the other parts).
[Properties of the co-countable topology on $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562358/properties-of-the-co-countable-topology-on-0-1)

Here is the exercise:

> Let $\tau$ be the system of sets consisting of the empty set and every
> subset of the closed unit interval $[0,1]$ obtained by deleting a finite or
> countable number of points from $X$. Verify that $T = (X,\tau)$ is a
> topological space. Prove that $T$ satisfies neither the second nor the
> first axiom of countability. Prove that $T$ is a $T_1$-space, but not
> a Hausdorff ($T_2$) space.

So, if I understand the problem statement, we can - as a simple example - remove the points $\{0.1, 0.2, \ldots, 0.9\}$ and get the topology:
$$
\tau = \{\emptyset, [0,0.1),\,(0.1,0.2)\,,\ldots,\,(0.8,0.9),\,(0.9,1]\}
$$
What I don't understand is how this could be a $T_1$ space. If you have two distinct points $x,y\in(0.1,0.2)$ how do you get neighborhoods $x\in O_x$,$y\in O_y$ so $x\not\in O_y$ and $y\not\in O_x$? Wouldn't I need open sets "smaller" than the ones defined in the topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote here:

$$
\tau = \{\emptyset, [0,0.1),\,(0.1,0.2)\,,\ldots,\,(0.8,0.9),\,(0.9,1]\}
$$

is not really the $\tau$ the exercise refers to.

Read the definition again. Given two distinct points $x,y\in [0,1]$ there is open subset in $\tau$ containing one of them but not the other, e.g. $[0,x)\cup(x,1]=[0,1]\backslash\{x\}$.

Comment: Ah, yes! Now the exercise makes more sense. I didn't know if I had misunderstood the exercise or some of the theory. But I see now. Thanks!